# PHP / CSS: Chat function with left and right site wont in the right format

Tags: php, html, css, format

Im working on my first support system. My idea is, an chat function like whatsapp or other messengers. It means, the sender on the left site and the recipient on the right site.
My Problem is to get the Messages in the right format...

I use the admin parameter to set the answer on the right site.. but i dont know why the elements wont do a distance to each other.. But if the sender answer again, the message will appears on the different site but in the same line.

I try it with the `top:auto;` in css.. but it wont like i want. Maybe somebody of you know my Problem?

PHP/HTML:

```
              <div class="answer-containersec">
                  <div class="user-message-answersec">
                    <h1 class="user-message-namesec"><?php echo $user['username'] . " " . "am" . " " . $user['date'];?></h1>
                    <h1 class="user-message-firstsec"><?php echo ">" . " " . $user['message'];?></h1>
                  </div>
                </div><?php
              }
              else{
              ?><div class="answer-container">
                  <div class="admin-message-answer">
                    <h1 class="admin-message-name"><?php echo $user['username'] . " " . "am" . " " . $user['date'];?></h1>
                    <h1 class="admin-message-first"><?php echo ">" . " " . $user['message'];?></h1>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
.answer-containersec{
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  position: relative;
}
.user-message-answersec{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #230F17;
  height: auto;
  width: 30em;
  left: .5em;
  border: 1px solid #360F17;
  border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px #360F17;
}
.answer-container{
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  position: relative;
}
.admin-message-answer{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #230F17;
  height: auto;
  width: 30em;
  float:right;
  right: .5em;
  border: 1px solid #360F17;
  border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px #360F17;
}
```

So does it looks like:
[image]

Comment: For your specific problem, the PHP portion isn't relevant. Instead, view the rendered source in your browser and just post a minimal portion of the HTML and CSS that is related to the problem.

Comment: I restricted the code above.
Yeah, I figured it had something to do with that. However, I can't get the formatting right. I assume that these will automatically arrange themselves correctly because each element occupies 100% of the width, but no. I have already experimented with a few variants, but have not come to a suitable result.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thanks man, i solved my problem. Have a great Day!

Comment: that's great! Can you post your solution so that this can be resolved?